# C++ des encrypt with ecb

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption, openssl, des

I have this line code in C++

```
ecb_crypt((char *)&pKey->left, (char *)pResult, 8, DES_ENCRYPT);
```

I have to use this but.. I don't know how! I mean, someone gave me this and said "Please note that ecb_crypt comes from a standard encryption library (e.g. openSSL).".

Ok, so I've installed openSSL, but I can't find this function. I found something similar, but with different arguments (AES_ecb_encrypt).

So, I try to ask you: do you know where I can find ecb_encrypt with those arguments? Where? Is it in openSSL?

It is used, for example, in this way:

```
void DesEncrypt3Des(void *pResult, const void *pData, KEY_3DES *pKey)
{
    memcpy(pResult, pData, 8);
    ecb_crypt((char *)&pKey->left, (char *)pResult, 8, DES_ENCRYPT);
    ecb_crypt((char *)&pKey->right, (char *)pResult, 8, DES_DECRYPT);
    ecb_crypt((char *)&pKey->left, (char *)pResult, 8, DES_ENCRYPT);
}
```

Further, I don't have any idea what is DES_ENCRYPT in the parameter. I think it is a constant I have to define, but with which value?

**UPDATE** --> I'm using this in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: `ecb_crypt()` is not an OpenSSL function; it's provided by `libc6` (and thus not available with Windows). A quick look at the OpenSSL docs suggests [`DES_ecb_encrypt()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/des.html) as an alternative. As for the `DES_key_schedule` parameter, note this from the docs: *"Before a DES key can be used, it must be converted into the architecture dependent DES_key_schedule via the DES_set_key_checked() or DES_set_key_unchecked() function."* Hope that helps.

Comment: @DevSolar thanks... I hope it too! ;)

Comment: @DevSolar  int DES_set_key_checked(const_DES_cblock *key,
        DES_key_schedule *schedule);

my keys are simple unsigned char byte[8]... how convert them in const_DES_cblock? what is schedule?

Comment: Some docs reading would not go amiss. From the same page linked above: *"There are two phases to the use of DES encryption. The first is the generation of a DES_key_schedule from a key, the second is the actual encryption. A DES key is of type DES_cblock. This type is **consists of 8 bytes** with odd parity. The least significant bit in each byte is the parity bit. The **key schedule is an expanded form of the key; it is used to speed the encryption process**."*

Comment: @DevSolar it says also "Before a DES key can be used, it must be converted into the architecture dependent DES_key_schedule via the DES_set_key_checked() or DES_set_key_unchecked() function." but the DES_set_key_checked (or DES_set_key_unchecked) requires a DES_key_schedule  var in input!!! Are they fools? Or am I missing something?

Comment: done in this way, sorry I don't use C from a lot of time..
  DES_key_schedule* d;
  DES_set_key_unchecked((const_DES_cblock *)&pKey->left, d);

Comment: The function takes `const_DES_cblock *key, DES_key_schedule *schedule`. Notice the `const`: `key` is a pointer to the input structure, `schedule` is a pointer to the output structure. (You declare `DES_key_schedule myschedule;` and pass its address to the function so it can be initialized.)

Comment: You should not use the low level DES functions, key schedules and all that. The easiest (and elegant) way to use DES in OpenSSL is to deploy EVP in your application - it's a higher level interface provided by OpenSSL.

Comment: @DevSolar Hi devsolar, I have DES_ecb_encrypt and also DES_ecb3_encrypt. But now I'm again stucked.. why can't I find DES_ecb_decrypt and DES_ecb3_decrypt??

Comment: @PieroAlberto: *sigh*... please, I'm happy to help, but seriously, it's *right there* in the docs I had linked in my *first* reply. The docs for the function you're already using? "*If the encrypt argument is non-zero (DES_ENCRYPT), the input (cleartext) is encrypted in to the output (ciphertext) using the key_schedule specified by the schedule argument, previously set via DES_set_key. If encrypt is zero (DES_DECRYPT), the input (now ciphertext) is decrypted into the output (now cleartext).*"

Comment: @DevSolar thanks...and sorry for the dumb question..

Comment: @PieroAlberto: np. ;-) Also check Lesny's comment -- there *is* a higher-level API to OpenSSL. But if you got the DES functions to work already, you'll probably want to stick with that.